# Following Up About an Unsolicited Job Offer?

Tags: software-industry, job-offer, negotiation

I work as a front-end designer and developer for the e-commerce department of a retail giant. It's not exactly the work I want to be doing, so I've been taking on freelance clients, one of which is an agency in the area.

They approached me with an unsolicited proposition last week, saying they are interested in bringing me on their team as a developer/designer hybrid role (this was an unsolicited offer, and worth mentioning that I'm not actively searching for a new job).

I came in last week and discussed what I thought they needed to know in order to make me an offer — what I can bring to the table, how much I need to make, when I can start, and what kind of projects I'll be working on. It was far outside the realm of an interview, and I left thinking they were going to get back to me with an offer in a few days.

It has now been a week, and although I've reached out to my contact with questions regarding the ongoing freelance project I'm working on with them, I haven't heard anything more about their decision to make me an offer.

**How should I word an email to the company to inquire about their progress on making me an offer?** In typical interview fashion, I wouldn't want to be too persistent, but this is an unusual case in that they approached **me** for the job, discussed terms of hire, then vanished.

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You have a job.  You are doing freelance for them...  I would probably play hard to get.

The facts are is that the agency doesn't seem to have a defined role for you.  They might want you to work there but they aren't sure at what capacity.  This is probably not a good thing for you, especially when negotiating with them.

What you need to do is give them time and let them think about it.  I am assuming they approached you because you do good work - and better than they are getting from their average team member.  So just keep doing good work.

No you don't have to act like the conversations didn't happen but also nothing wrong with concentrating on your projects.  Seeming eager may hurt you money-wise and they might just stick you with a position, not necessarily what you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the job, then follow up on it. You can analyse the situation all you want, whether they decided you're too expensive etc,. but realistically you don't know anything until you ask.

One follow up does not make you look desperate or anything like that. It's the usual thing to do if you don't hear back within a reasonable time frame.